# Como habilitar e desabilitar scroll automático em um chat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rolamento, chat

Estou com dúvidas na implementação desse recurso.

Tenho um link que faz essa ação, tipo habilitar e desabilitar o scroll automático.

Para melhor entendimento, acesse o JSFIDDLE abaixo:

**[EXEMPLO NO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tzr5fz8b/)**

Comment: Porque não usa o `data` do `jQuery`? assim você pode fazer algo tipo `<div id="list_msg" data-scroll-habilitado="false">`. Aí você faz um `if`. Se for true, você faz `$("#list_msg").scrollTop($("#list_msg").prop('scrollHeight'))`

Comment: Boa @WallaceMaxters, num tinha pensado nisso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para fazer a troca do scroll automático, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var msg = $("#msg");

    $("#send_msg").click(function(){
        if(msg.val().length >= 1){
            $("#list_msg").append("<li>"+msg.val()+"</li>")
            msg.val("").focus();
        }

       // verifica se o scroll automático está habilitado (atualmente)

        if ($("#list_msg").data('scroll-habilitado') === true) {
              var scrollHeight = $("#list_msg").prop('scrollHeight');
              $("#list_msg").scrollTop(scrollHeight);
        }
    })

    $("#scroll_enable_disable").click(function(){
        var currentStatus = $("#list_msg").data('scroll-habilitado');
       // faz o toggle de status
       $("#list_msg").data('scroll-habilitado', !currentStatus);
    })
})
```

E por padrão, você pode definir se vai vir habilitado ou não, da seguinte forma:

```
<ul id="list_msg" data-scroll-habilitado="true"></ul>
```

E como foi pedido um exemplo no **JsFiddle**, aqui vai:

http://jsfiddle.net/tzr5fz8b/3/

Comment: Só esqueci de deixar a troca de textos como estava antes. Mas você vai me perdoar por isso ;)

Comment: Muito bom @WallaceMaxters! Obrigado, é bem isso que preciso.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tzr5fz8b/4/ Com os textos corretos :)